# MIPS Exception 6 [Bad instruction address] for Newton's Method of finding Square Roots

Tags: exception, assembly, mips, qtspim

I'm trying to implement Newton's Method for calculating integer square roots of a given k ($a0 here). I get the correct output but it is followed by an infinite series of Exception 6 errors like the following:

```
sqrt(32) = 5
sqrt(33) = 5
sqrt(34) = 5
sqrt(35) = 6
sqrt(36) = 6
sqrt(37) = 6
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000024
  Bad address in text read: 0x00000025
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000028
  Bad address in text read: 0x00000028
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x0000002c
  Bad address in text read: 0x0000002c
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000030
  Bad address in text read: 0x00000030
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000034
  Bad address in text read: 0x00000034
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x00000038
  Bad address in text read: 0x00000038
  Exception 6  [Bad instruction address]  occurred and ignored
```

Could anyone take a look at my code and diagnose the problem? Thanks.

Comment: That can't be your entire program. I don't see any code in there that prints anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` function saves the value of `$ra` in `$s0` and assumes that `$s0` will remain unchanged, but the `sqrt` function will modify `$s0`.

Either save `$ra` in a different register, or on the stack.
Or replace the `jr $s0` with:

```
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: this fixed the problem. Thank you so much:)